# Infinite Intersection of closed subintervals

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, solution-verification

This is from Jay Cummings Real Analysis 1.34

Question: For each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, assume we are given a closed interval $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$. Also, assume that each $I_{n+1}$ is contained inside of $I_n$. Prove that $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}I_n$ is non-empty.

Proof by induction:

(Base case) $n=1 \ a_1$ is contained within $I_n$, this is the only set in the interesction therefor it is non-empty.

$n=m+1$

$a_{m+1}$ is in the interval, by induction it is proved that $a_{m+1}$ is in every interval $I_b \ 0<b < m+1$.

The base case $b={m+1}$ is clear.

$b=j-1 \ \ \ \ \ \ $ $I_j\subseteq I_{j-1} \, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ a_{m+1}\in I_j\implies a_{m+1}\in I_{j-1}$

Therefor for $n=m+1$ it is true that $a_{m+1}$ is in $I_n$, therefor it is nonempty.

Comment: You cannot use induction. You did not prove at all that $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}I_n$ is non-empty.

Comment: Hint:  Show that $\sup_i a_i \in \cap_n I_n$

Comment: @geetha290krm so, why can you not use induction?

Comment: Proving that $\bigcap^\infty_{n=1}I_n$ is non-empty is not the same as proving that each $I_n$ is non-empty.

Comment: @geetha290krm yeah okay right I had a talk with someone